# Is it possible to configure the directory for sbatch's default output file?

Tags: slurm

Is there some way to configure an alternative default directory (other than the current directory) for `sbatch` to put the file `slurm-%j.out` (or `slurm-%A_%a.out`) that it generates when the `-o` is not specified?

My goals here are to have a convenient/low-maintenance way to

1. consolidate all default output files generated by `sbatch` in one place; and
2. avoid cluttering the current directory with such files.

I had hoped to find something like a `SLURM_DEFAULT_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` environment variable to take care of this, but if there is such a variable, I managed to miss it.

Is there some other mechanism to achieve the desired results?

---

(FWIW, the only precedent that comes to mind for the functionality I'm after is Emacs's `backup-directory-alist`, which tells Emacs were to put the backup files it generates by default.  This feature is more sophisticated than what I'm after, because it supports multiple such directories, to be used according to patterns in the original filenames.)

Answer (score 19):

Pass a log file into a folder as follows in bash script:

```
#SBATCH -o ./Report/output.%a.out # STDOUT
```

This will put the output files in "Report" folder next to your batch script.

Comment: does this command create `Report` folder is does not already exist?

Comment: From my tests it would appear not.

Comment: No, it does not!

Comment: You need to create the "Report" folder first!!!! The ouput file will not show up if you didn't create one.

Answer (score 7):

The **.sh** file below will save the slurm output .out file at

"***/home/YOUR_USER/lustre/PROJECT/output/%j.out***"

where %j is the jobid of the running job as explained [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html).

So, in the output directory mentioned above you'll find something similar to this:

**399937.out**

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=JOB_ID_NAME
#SBATCH --time=4-00:00          # adjust this to match the walltime of your job
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=28      # adjust this if you are using parallel commands
#SBATCH --mem=1000              # adjust this according to the memory requirement per node you need
#SBATCH --mail-user=YOUR-EMAIL  # adjust this to match your email address
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --output=/home/YOUR_USER/lustre/PROJECT/output/%j.out
```

Comment: I tried this with `-o` and it tries to find "/home/YOUR_USER/lustre/PROJECT/output/%j.out" in the current directory that the bash script is rather than go to the specified directory.

Answer (score 1):

An other option is to use a [Job Submit Plugin](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_submit_plugins.html).

You can write such a plugin either in `C` or in `LUA` so it forces the output file (default base name but your own directory in your case) if not already set by the script nor the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and my solution was to copy the submission script into the directory designated for the output. I then ran the script located in the output directory. The directory of the code intended to be submitted with SLURM can be communicated dynamically to the job script via an environment variable. The code directory can also be set as the working directory before executing the code. I hope somebody finds this solution helpful.